# Suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are reflexive relations on a set A. Is $R_1 \cap R_2$ also reflexive? Is $R_1 \cup R_2$ also reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

My book says that both of these statements are true. I don't understand why the first is true. Suppose $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and define the relations as follows:

$R_1 = \{(1, 1), (2, 2)\} $

$R_2 = \{(3, 3), (4, 4)\}$

These two relations are reflexive, but the intersection is the empty set. The empty set is not reflexive for a non-empty set $A$. Why am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these relations is reflexive: Reflexivity means that for **all** elements $a \in A, (a,a) \in R$. In this case, $(3,3) \notin R_1$ and $(1,1) \notin R_2$.

Comment: Damn it, I think I'm too tired to think today, lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but a relation is reflexive if $(x,x) \in R$ for all $x\in A$.  Hence neither of the two relations that you give are reflexive.

To see that the intersection of two reflexive relations is reflexive, suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are reflexive.  Then
$$R_1 \cap R_2 = \{ (x,y) : (x,y) \in R_1 \land (x,y) \in R_2 \}.$$
But we know that for any $x\in A$, we have $(x,x)\in R_1$, and $(x,x) \in R_2$, therefore $(x,x) \in R_1 \cap R_2$.  Therefore $R_1 \cap R_2$ is reflexive.

The union is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these relations is reflexive.  For a relation $R$ on a set $A$ to be reflexive, we must have $(x,x)\in R$ for *all* $x\in A$.  Your relations satisfy this only for some of the elements of the set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

It is true that your $R_1$ is reflexive as a relation on the set $B=\{1,2\}$ and $R_2$ is reflexive as a relation on the set $C=\{3,4\}$.  But the statement in your book requires $R_1$ and $R_2$ to be reflexive relations on the *same* set $A$.